# Is is possible for rsync to partly copy a file, if a process gets killed?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

My assumption about `rsync` is that it transfers the file in a "sync"hronous way, meaning that it's all-or-nothing. Is this correct, or is it possible that `rsync` could return a non-0 and still have persisted something on the remote disk under the intended name? In other words, I `rsync` `myfile.txt` from server A to server B as `/myfile.txt`. The transfer fails for some reason (one server crashes or the process is killed at just the right time). Now, is it possible for `/myfile.txt` to have been created on server B, or does `rsync` do something with temp files (or other) to ensure the file has been transferred entirely and then renames it?

Note, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2, in case that matters, and I don't have cached write-back nonsense on my disks for performance or anything (if the disk says it's complete, the write is complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the man page of rsync you will see that it has a `--delay-updates`option which sounds relevant for your needs.

> This option puts the temporary file from each updated file into a holding directory until the end of the transfer, at which time all the files are renamed into place in rapid succession. This attempts to make the updating of the files a little more atomic. By default the files are placed into a directory named lq.~tmp~rq in each file's destination directory, but if you've specified the **--partial-dir** option, that directory will be used instead. See the comments in the **--partial-dir** section for a discussion of how this lq.~tmp~rq dir will be excluded from the transfer, and what you can do if you want rsync to cleanup old lq.~tmp~rq dirs that might be lying around. Conflicts with **--inplace** and **--append**.

Update:
It will return only 0 on success, and values **NOT** 0 on errors according to the man page.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if `rsync` will return a 0 response in any situation that hasn't resulted in the file being created exactly as you intended it (baring kernel bugs and hardware issues)? I'm using `rsync` to archive my WAL logs and I just want to make sure it'll never lie to my database.

Comment: It should not return 0 if the copy is not a complete success. The man page will describe the various different exit codes it can return.